# Closure allocation and passing by reference

Tags: c#, closures

I have a function which looks like:

```
private void OnItemChannelsListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs args)
{
...
int index = args.NewIndex;
this.UpdateLogsOnNewAssignedUnit(ref index, channels);
}
```

where

```
private void UpdateLogsNewAssignedUnit(ref int index, List<IChannel> channels)
{
}
```

I use a plugin called Heap Allocations Viewer plugin (ps. I am not affiliated with them) which visually displays heap allocations on the editor. Well, in the ref int index argument underneath it displays

> Closure allocation: 'index', 'channels' parameters and 'this' reference

From my understanding, passing an int ref should not create a new copy! 
Does anyone know why does it happen and what can I do to avoid it?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: If you're digging to that level, I'd say use ILSpy to take a look at where the closure's being created. I can't see any obvious closure in your code. Maybe it's happening inside the `UpdateLogsNewAssignedUnit` method? Are you inadvertently creating a closure in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this

```
private void OnItemChannelsListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs args)
```

I think you're firing an event, you don't "have a function" as you say in your 1st line.

If you call the UpdateLogsNewAssignedUnit function from outside the event handler, I'd wager that the allocation doesn't happen. Events are typically implemented as multicast delegates (they don't HAVE to be, but typically are). Since you're calling it from an event handler, the compiler is creating a state object to use in the invocation. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/03/10263921.aspx) article for more information. Specifically:

> Before lambdas/anonymous methods were introduced, C# developers wanting to call a method that accepted a delegate would typically need to define a class to store their state, add a method to that class to do their processing, and then create a delegate that pointed to that method on that state instance, e.g.

```
    public static void WriteOnPool(Stream stream, byte [] data) 
    { 
        var state = new WriteOnPoolState(); 
        state.stream = stream; 
        state.data = data; 
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(state.Invoke)); 
    } 

    private sealed class WriteOnPoolState 
    { 
        public Stream stream; 
        public byte [] data; 

        public void Invoke(object ignored) 
        { 
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); 
        }    
    }
```

> Now in C#, when you use an anonymous method or lambda, the compiler actually ends up generating code almost identical to this on your behalf so that you no longer have to do so manually.  Here’s a decompiled version of what gets generated for my previous example that used an anonymous method:

```
    public static void WriteOnPool(Stream stream, byte[] data) 
    { 
        var locals2 = new DisplayClass1(); 
        locals2.stream = stream; 
        locals2.data = data; 
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( 
            new WaitCallback(locals2.<WriteOnPool>b__0)); 
    } 

    [CompilerGenerated] 
    private sealed class DisplayClass1 
    { 
        public Stream stream; 
        public byte[] data; 

        public void <WriteOnPool>b__0(object param0) 
        { 
            this.stream.Write(this.data, 0, this.data.Length); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: ok i know that the price to pay for an int is small in my case, but hypothetically speaking would it be better to avoid creating a new function which is called from within the event and instead keep on writing the logic within the event?

Comment: I'm not sure that makes sense. Does whether the caller is an event handler or not really matter? `OnItemChannelsListChanged` is just a normal method. It doesn't know about how it's called. The closure we're seeing is internal to the method, not external. The `index` isn't even in the picture until we're already in the method. What you're implying is that the emitted IL is different for `OnItemChannelsListChanged` depending on the caller. Is that really the case here? Are multiple different copies of `OnItemChannelsListChanged` generated depending on how it's called? Doesn't sound right.

Comment: @Baldrick Yes; think of each instance of an event handler (each +=) as an instance of a delegate; because that delegate accesses data from the class and invokes the method via 'this', the compiler wants to create a state object for the data. I don't have the tool to confirm that this is the case, but I think that is what is happening.

Comment: @FatGiant can you confirm that the allocation doesn't happen if you just call UpdateLogsNewAssignedUnit from a console app or unit test?

Comment: @AllanElder: In that case, surely the closure would need to grab `sender`, `args`, and `this` from the caller at the point the delegate is created. The internals of the method `OnItemChannelsListChanged` would not be relevant for creating *that* delegate.

Comment: @AllanElder: I tried to call it from a non event method + from a unit test. Still the same..

Comment: I would guess, at that point, this is more likely a false flag from the Heap Allocation tool. ReSharper has done this to me before. As @Baldrick pointed out, for this to be the case, the compiler would need to grab much more info for state.